# Google Sheets Query where column matches data on another sheets column range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to query only result that match a pre-defined list in Google Sheets.

This formula is working...but what if my WHERE list contains thousands of entries? Is there a better way?

```
=QUERY(DATA!A2:B,"SELECT B WHERE A = 'Data 1' OR A = 'Data 6' OR A = 'Data 8'")
```

---

Sheet #1 - Contains the data I would like to query.

```
|   A    |      B      |
| Data 1 | Something 1 |
| Data 2 | Something 2 |
| Data 3 | Something 3 |
| Data 4 | Something 4 |
| Data 5 | Something 5 |
```

Sheet #2 - Contains a pre-defined list (Column A) & a query formula (Colum B).

```
|   A   |     B      |
| Data1 | Something1 |
| Data6 | Something6 |
| Data8 | Something8 |
```

Here is the formula I have tried:

```
=QUERY(DATA!A2:B,"SELECT B WHERE A = '"&A2:A&"'")
```

Here is my Google Sheet: [Click Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pddswrYmbh2VCO-da9jazNKz9EJuhV7oO0RJXAYplEA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in cell `Formula!C2`:

`=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup(A2:A, DATA!A2:B, columns(DATA!A2:B), false) ) )`

Comment: That's a great solution and works flawlessly. Thank you. Is there any way to achieve these results using query instead?

Comment: Yes, but it would be quite complex. Why would it be necessary to use `query()` when another lookup solution is much simpler?

Comment: I agree, simple is best. The only reason for query is because its "faster" than vlookup. The real dataset that i'm working with is around 40,000 rows x 6 columns. I would also like to learn more about the query function and its limitations.

Comment: This formula will give the same results **but** only as long as the keys in column `A` are unique and in alphabetical order: `=query(DATA!A2:B, "select B where A matches '" & "^" & textjoin("$|^", true, A2:A) & "$' ", 0)`

Comment: You are amazing! That works perfectly! Thank you!